# Apache logs AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, log-files

I'm new to AWS and just created an AWS EC2 instance using Ubuntu to host a website. The website is up and running but whenever I got in /var/log/apache2 to view the access.log file, it shows the public ip address when I access the site on my phone and computer, meaning I can't differentiate between the two devices.

How can I get it to show my PC IP and phone IP address instead of using public IP address?

Comment: AWS has no visiblity into your network. Your devices would need separate public IPs for AWS to see them as such.

Comment: is there not a way to log the client ip address?

Comment: The client IP address is the same for all devices on your home network. Configure apache to log the user agent if you need to know what device is accessing the website.